# Yeoman generator code highlight for webstorm

Tags: webstorm, yeoman-generator

I am creating yeoman generator and i came accross problem with code inspection in webstorm.
Here is my code:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
      // Process main less file to css file in build folder
      less: {
      <% if (includeBootstrap) { %>
```

i get syntax error near <% and the whole file highlighting is ruined.
How to make it ok. I suppose i should use ESJ highlighting but I can't set it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the following:

- in `Settings | Editor | File Types`, add 'Gruntfile.js' (or whatever
  your file is named) to '`EJS`' registered patterns (actual name for
  EJS file type there is `'EJS combines data...`')
- click on the added pattern, press Edit, in `Template data language`
  dropdown choose 'JavaScript'